# Changing the name of model in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, django, orm

I wanted to change the name of a model

From:

```
class GreenPost(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
 text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

 def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.user.id) + " -- " + self.text

class GreenMessage(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.post.user.username) + " -- " + self.text
```

To :

```
class Post(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
 text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

 def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.user.id) + " -- " + self.text

class Message(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.post.user.username) + " -- " + self.text
```

If I just apply the migration, the django ORM will drop my old database tables and create new tables. Thus, deleting any data that I may have in the database.

What's a way that I can rename the models , but still keep the data and the same relationships ex(Foreign Key's)?

Answer (score 3):

The autodetector is probably getting confused because you're changing both `Models` at once. Try changing one name at a time, running `makemigrations` each time.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you can create your own migrations file (using `makemigrations --empty`) and use the [`RenameModel`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/#renamemodel) operation.